# MySQL range selection with wildcards

Tags: mysql, regex, range, wildcard

Is it possible to select a database entry based on some of the first characters of a string, matching with a 'range' in a column with MySQL?

I'll try to make this more clear by an example:
I need to select a database entry by matching a zipcode, but we retrieved the zipcodes from another system in 'ranges', such as 100-128. The zipcode 10001 (New York) needs to match this entry. The first 3 digits of the zipcode needs to match with 100 or 128, or anything in between (101, 102, ... 126, 127).

So, the database entries are all like 050-051, 144-146, 245-253 etc., which I need to match with a full zipcode.

Is it somehow possible to select this entry with a query?

Any help is appreciated!

Edit:
I'll try to make it more clear:

I have just one zipcode, entered by a user, for example, 10001 (NY).

Now I want to retrieve all the entries of my shipping info table, which match with a range (100-128).

User zipcode: 07200, retrieve entries with range: 064-089

User zipcode: 33101, retrieve entries with range: 330-334

And so on.

My shipping info table has the following columns:

ID, country_id, zip_range, price

Comment: What about [MySql Regex](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html)? E.g. `...WHERE my_col RLIKE '^1([01][0-9]|2[0-8])'`

Comment: How would you automate turning a string like `100-128` into that regexp? And how would you do it in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to split the ranges apart into the beginning and end. Then match zipcodes whose first three characters are in that range with `BETWEEN`.

```
SELECT *
FROM shippingInfo
WHERE LEFT(:zipcode, 3) BETWEEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(ziprange, '-', 1) AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(ziprange, '-', -1);
```

`:zipcode` is a placeholder that gets the user-inputted zipcode.

Comment: This answer is close, but not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm not joining any tables actually, I have just one table that has my shipping info (with columns such as ziprange, price, country). I can't seem to get this to work..

Comment: Where are the full zipcodes that you're matching with? I think you need to update your question with more details. Show a sample of the table, and what you're trying to get as a result.

Comment: I think that once you saw the functions I was using in my join, this answer should have been obvious. It's exactly the same, except it matches against the input instead of a column in another table.